# Unity C# Error: 'Sprite' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: visual-studio, c#, ubuntu-unity

I've been working on an item system for my game in Unity. I am still pretty new to coding, but I am giving it my best effort.

My Item system Works by accessing interfaces with the data I need. While trying to assign my sprite from the interface to a private variable, I get the error "'Sprite' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments." I have looked all over for solutions, and haven't found any fixes that have worked for me so far.

The Class I created to access the interface looks like this:

```
public class ISType : IISType {

    [SerializeField] string _name;

    [SerializeField] Sprite _icon;

    ISType()
    {
        _name = "Type";
        _icon = new Sprite(); }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        { return _name; }

        set
        { _name = value }
    }

    public Sprite Icon {
        get
        { return _icon; }

        set
        { _icon = value; }
}
```

}

If anyone can tell what is going on I would really appreciate the help! :)

Comment: The answer is in the error. There is no constructor that takes 0 parameters for Sprite. Without seeing the code I'm guessing you made a custom constructor with parameters and didn't add a paramaterless one. If you have further questions, you'll need to post this to StackOverflow instead as programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How would I go about creating a parameter less constructor? I am still a little shaky on the code skills. Here is my interface if you need to see that 

'code'

    public interface IISType
    {

        string Name { get; set; }

        Sprite Icon { get; set; }

    }
'code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Sprite does not contain a public constructor accepting zero arguments.

A class with no constructors defined will have a parameterless constructor.

```
public class MyClass { }

MyClass x= new MyClass(); // this is valid
```

However if it has any other constructors defined, this parameterless 'default' constructor is no longer 'a given'.

> **Difference between default constructor and paramterless constructor?**
>
> Answer by Nicole Calinoiu
>
> The "default" constructor is added by the C# compiler if your class does not contain an explicit instance constructor. It is a public, parameterless constructor.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/10498709/5569485

```
public class MyClass { 
    public MyClass(string foo)
    { 
    }
}

MyClass x= new MyClass(); // this is invalid
```

The class would have to manually define a parameterless constructor.

```
public class MyClass { 
   // parameterless constructor
    public MyClass()
    { 
    }

    public MyClass(string foo)
    { 
    }
}

MyClass x= new MyClass(); // this is valid again!
```

Sometimes no constructors are provided publicly, and a class instead provides static methods to instantiate the object.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyClass()
    {
    }

    public static MyClass Create()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/private-constructors
>
> A private constructor is a special instance constructor. It is generally used in classes that contain static members only. If a class has one or more private constructors and no public constructors, other classes (except nested classes) cannot create instances of this class.

Without knowing more about the `Sprite` class, my guess is that there is a static method for creating instances of the Sprite

something like

```
Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(...);
```

Comment: This was it. I fixed the error after I looked into the Sprite class and finding the Sprite.Create command and then finding the parameters it takes. I then passed the parameters I needed from the interface to my class and viola! It works like a charm! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error. There is no constructor that takes 0 parameters for Sprite. Without seeing the code I'm guessing you made a custom constructor with parameters and didn't add a paramaterless one.

A default parameterless constructor would look like:

```
Sprite()
{}
```

Be sure to do a lot more reading and tutorials. This is fairly basic class information.